# C language. Pointer on array and array

Tags: arrays, pointers

Pascal:

```
type
    TA = packed record
        b: Char;    
        c: LongInt; 
    end;
    TAA = array[1..255] of TA;
var
    D: LongInt;
    Z: LongInt;
    N: array[0..10] of packed record
        F: LongInt;      
        Y: LongInt;          
        WL, WW: Word; 
        E: ^TAA;           
    end;    
var 
 b_var:char;
i,j:longint;
...
        b_var := N[i].E^[j].b;
```

C language:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char b;           
    signed long int c;
} TA;
typedef TA TAA[256]; 
signed long int D;
signed long int Z;
struct
{
    signed long int F;     
    signed long int Y;         
    unsigned int WL, WW;
    TAA *E;                  
} N[11];
...
//      b_var = N[i].*E[j].b;   /*is not allowed by compiler*/
//      b_var = N[i].(*E)[j].b; /*is not allowed by compiler*/
//      b_var = N[i].E[j]->b;   /*allowed by compiler, but no one knows is it same as Pascal */
```

This code does not work. Works b_var = N[i].E[j]->b;
, but is it same as Pascal's code? E[j] is interpreted as element of array or as element of a pointer?

Comment: Where is the `typedef` for `TOutArr`? What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it correct understanding of pointer on array https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/53/240791000.0/0_17daa3_f02a9eaf_orig.png ? If it is correct then b_var = N[i].*E[j].b; and b_var = N[i].E[j]->b; is not the same . So what should I do to keep Pascal logic? –

[] has higher priority then dereference. I think I must therefore use b_var = N[i].(*E)[j].b;. But in this case I got error syntax error : '(' –

Or maybe I should use b_var = N[i].E[0][j].b; ?

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays and pointers are practically the same thing. Because of this, `E[j]` is a syntactic sugar to `*(E + sizeof(TOutArr)*j)`, you need to understand that. `var->b` is a syntactic sugar to `(*var).b` when working with pointers to structs.

In this line:

```
N[i].E[j]->b
```

`N[i]` accesses element of array N at index i (which is a struct)

`E[j]` accesses element of array E at index j (which is a pointer to a struct)

`->b` accesses struct element through a pointer to struct

You didn't initialize `E` which is defined as a pointer. And variables must always be initialized in C before you can use them (pointers especially, since trying to access value through an uninitialized pointer will result in memory access error or memory corruption).

Comment: Yes , array and pointer is same. But is same pointer on array and array?

Comment: Because you are attempting the **dereference an uninitialized pointer** which is **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: So pointer on array is a pointer on pointer on first element. But array is a pointer on first element. I can get 1st element by *(pointer on first element). How can I get 1st element if I have (pointer on pointer on first element)?

Comment: When you declare a pointer `TAA *E`, then `E` is just an 8-byte pointer to a memory address. No memory address is assigned to `E` so it points to nothing. You must `allocate` memory for `E` and then `E` will hold the starting address to that memory block. (e.g. for each `N[i]` you need `N[i]->E = malloc (sizeof TAA)` or `N[i]->E = malloc (256 * sizeof (struct TA))` If you declare E statically, `TAA E` instead, then your `N[i].E[j].b` notation will work.

Comment: In Pascal code there is only    `FillChar(N, SizeOf(N), 0);`  . No other memory allocation or something similar.

Comment: C gives your the power to manage your own allocation of memory on the heap -- but with great power comes great responsibility... When you simply declare `TAA E` space for an `array of struct TA[256]` is reserved on the stack for E. However, when you declare `TAA *E`, you create a **pointer to** an `array of struct TA[256]`. You then must allocate space for the `array of struct TA[256]` assigning the address of the block to `E`. You are then responsible for freeing that memory when you are done. The key is the stack has limited size, the heap is limited to your available `RAM`.

Comment: I just need to port pascal code to C language. What should I do? "C gives your the power to manage your own allocation of memory on the heap" -- But it's stupid. If I declare **sized** array, it is obvious I will use it. So I need a memory. And compiler knows how many memory I need (256*(1+4) bytes) .

Comment: N[i]->E = malloc (sizeof TAA) gives compiler error ` left operand has 'struct' type, use '.' ` N[i].E = malloc (sizeof TAA) gives compiler error  `'TAA' : illegal use of this type as an expression `

Comment: N[i].E = malloc (sizeof (TAA))  is allowed by compiler, but there is error in b_var = N[i].*E[j].b; `syntax error : '*'`

Comment: Is it correct understanding of pointer on array https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/53/240791000.0/0_17daa3_f02a9eaf_orig.png ? If it is correct then `b_var = N[i].*E[j].b;` and `b_var = N[i].E[j]->b;` is not the same . So what should I do to keep Pascal logic?

Comment: [] has higher priority then dereference. I think I must therefore use `b_var = N[i].(*E)[j].b;`. But in this case I got error `syntax error : '('`

Comment: Or maybe I should use `b_var = N[i].E[0][j].b;`